# pgrep -f command in ssh through script gives a wrong result. how to solve this issue

Tags: bash, shell

When I am trying to use `pgrep -f <proc_name>` command in ssh through script gives a wrong result. How to solve this issue? (I used RSA key for not to ask p/w)

```
ssh -l $UNAME $HOST bash -c "'
        pgrep -f name > p_id
        '"
```

Comment: "script gives a wrong result" is not an error description.

Comment: Its not an error description... actually the above statement giving two process ids instead of one. when i use the same pgrep in remote machine it gives only one process id.

Comment: Crossposting: https://superuser.com/q/1261249/340330

Comment: Replace `-f` by `-fo`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without more details, but my guess is that it's detecting the `bash` process. The way you're doing it, the remote ssh daemon is running `bash -c '<newline>pgrep -f name > p_id<newline>', which then runs`pgrep -f name`(with output to the file "p_id"). Note that`ps -f`searches the entire command line for matches, so the "name" part of the argument to`bash` is probably matching itself.

One option is to use the old trick to keep `ps | grep something` from matching itself: use `[n]ame` instead of just `name`. But then you need quotes around it, so the quoting gets even more complicated than it already is. It looks simpler to me to just skip the `bash -c` part and one layer of quoting:

```
ssh -l $UNAME $HOST 'pgrep -f name >p_id'
```

Comment: ssh -l $UNAME $PRI_HOST 'pgrep -f name >tmp.pid'

Gordon tried as you suggested. in the place of name i just used my process name. Still i am getting two entries in tmp.pid file.  where first entry is the correct one & the second entry(2nd line) is unknown pid for me.

Comment: @Raj If you manually ssh into the remote computer, can you see if the second one is an existing process? Also, try `ssh ... 'ps $(pgrep -f name)'` and see what it prints.

Comment: no i am not
 cat /proc/58453/cmdline
cat: /proc/58453/cmdline: No such file or directory. where as for other process id i am getting. 
ok I will try it now. Thanks.

Comment: ssh ... 'ps $(pgrep -f name)' 
tried this.... it listed PID for my 'process name' & 'ps' as well

Comment: That sounds like it's matching the shell that's running commands on the remote computer (before it execs `ps`). Try the `[]` trick on the first letter of the name you're looking for (but add double-quotes around it, like `'pgrep -f "[n]ame" >p_id'`).

Comment: Thanks Gordon this seems working fine from cmd prompt, i will incorporate in my script & will test.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Could you please include the [n]ame trick in your answer? Upvoted in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any code from the script, but first look at user permissions, they may be the reason for process command returning different results. Other potential trouble spots are:

Check script permissions and verify execute options. Make sure script    user has the correct permissions for the directory where that process    runs.

You ran the command via the command prompt, is that with the    same user that is executing the script?  If not it may be    permissions.

Put the -u option in your pgrep command for the user who    owns the process you are looking for. Or try inserting an sudo    command into the script and run the pgrep as another user, one with    admin/root-like privileges.

And don't forget to read the man pages, perhaps there's an option you need.